# Running a java program from a eclipse Plugin Handler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to run a java program from a an event handler from my eclipse plugin. 
I have recently started to experiment with eclipse plug ins. I want to run a java file from the sample handler.

I ave tried calling it like this : java.main(args) 
THIS DID not work since it could not find 'args'

i also tried to make a main method but that also failed.

```
    package plugintest.handlers;

    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.eclipse.core.commands.AbstractHandler;
    import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent;
    import org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException;
    import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchWindow;
    import org.eclipse.ui.handlers.HandlerUtil;
    import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;

    public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
           public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
           IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
           MessageDialog.openInformation(
            window.getShell(),
            "PluginTest",
            "Hello, Eclipse world");  


           return null;
         }
  }
```

the java program that I am trying to run is in the same project and folder as the samplehandler.

Comment: right above RETURN NULL,

Comment: I added example.main(args). And it doesnt work.

Comment: Calling a traditional Java program directly from a handler is going to cause the UI to lock up until the program finishes. You would need to launch it in a separate JVM.